# Distributing objects between guides not working properly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, guides

I've had this issue with Illustrator 5.5, 6 and CC, usually I work around it, but today I am sorta frustrated with the issue and decided to try and find a permanent solution.

It doesn't happen all the times, but sometimes when I try to evenly distribute objects between guide lines it won't distribute then right and actually moves one of the guides out of place.

I attach an image to explain better.
[image: example]

here's a better example I made
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I can't replicate the problem. It seems to work as expected when I try it, although I need to switch to "Align to: Selection". Is this the problem perhaps?  I can't work out what option you have selected, since the icon shown in your screen shot is different in my copy of Illustrator CC 2018.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't happen all the time and happens more often if you're working for web (pixels instead of mms and 72 dpi instead of 300), but when it happens I often have the create a new document to fix it, or work around it.
I do know the difference between align to selection or artboard, so that is not the issue.
thanks :)

Comment: added an image to show better

Comment: I can't replicate that behaviour at all, despite trying several times, even tried with web and print documents. Perhaps time to contact Adobe?

Comment: I figured an easy work around it, apparently the issue has to do with the guides being on the edge of the work area, so if I select everything and distribute it will not move the left guide (or object if I have an object instead of a guide) and will move the right guide to either left or right depending on the size of the objects in between. Now, if I select everything, press right, so that the guides are no longer on the edge, then it will distribute alright, then I can press left and everything goes into place smoothly.

Comment: Hmm . . . it doesn't make any difference when I put the guides on the edge of the work area, so I doubt that's the real source of the problem. Something else is up I think. Have you tried resetting your preferences file, or upgrading to the latest version? I'm voting to close this now as it seems to be a tech support issue.

Comment: atm I use CS6 and can't pay for newer versions, I've reinstalled and reset preferences and it still happens and it has happened to me randomly on CS cloud 2019 back when I was still subscribing that.

Comment: Why don't you use 3 objects and then make them horizontal distribute?

Answer (score 0):

is `Allign To` is selected to `Allign to Selection` ? and are you selecting only necessary layers? (2 rects and 2 guides) cuz it seems you might be selecting hidden or unnecessary layers which is out side of guide area only then guide will move. watch below image

[image]

Comment: The align is set to selection I and not to artboard, I am familiar with using both options when convenient so that's that not the issue.
Also, I've actually run into an issue before where I was selecting hidden stuff grouped with a layer that messed things up, but this is not it, the problem is exactly as I described, I believe it's related with the issue some users have where objects are set by default to align to pixel grid with makes them not align well with eachother, this must be some similar option on the document creation that messes things up.

Comment: I added one animated gif illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue as the OP... Objects were not distributing properly (or so I thought) with no hidden items or other weirdness going on that would easily explain the issue. It also appeared to be intermittent. Finally figured out what was going on for me.. not sure this will solve the problem involving the guides, but maybe. Here's my fix:

[image]

The "Distribute Objects to Selection" function spaces things out perfectly (to your eye) only when they are the same size. Assuming you have the reference point set to center...

[image]

...than Illustrator will *always* evenly distribute the items based on that center point. However, if objects are of different sizes, this distribution can create the appearance of the spacing being uneven. This is because Illustrator is measuring distances based only on the center reference point.

If you want to evenly distribute objects within a selection that are different sizes, select your objects, then click the "Distribute Spacing," button, (the same button you would use to space out objects relative to a key object), but with no value specified:

[image]

Here's an example for you:

**THE ISSUE**
These are 3 different sized objects, evenly distributed by the center reference point. Nothing about this looks evenly distributed, BUT the distance between each object's center point is actually identically spaced--focus your eyes on the center, blue dot of each square and you'll see this is correct. It's sort of an optical illusion!

[image]

**THE FIX:**
Highlight your 3 images and click the "Distribute Spacing" button, and you're money. Hope this helps.. someone.
[image]